# What operators to implement with int members

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a class that has a few int and a const int member with a constructor defined.

```
class SomeContainer
{
    public:
        SomeContainer():
            member1(0),
            member2(staticMethod())
        {}
    private:
         static int staticMethod();
         int member1;
         const int member2;
}
```

I need to create an assignment operator since I use this class in another class MainClass and code

```
MainClass* p1;
MainClass* p2
{
    //...
    *p1 = *p2 // fails since SomeContainer doesn't have copy assignment operator
}
```

Should this code be enough or am I missing anything?

```
{
    SomeContainer(const SomeContainer& other): // copy ctor
        member1(other.member1),
        member2(other.member2)
    {}


    SomeContainer& operator=(const SomeContainer& other)  // assignment operator
    {
      member1 = other.member1;
    }
}
```

what about move ctor and move assignment? Should I need to implement those as well?

Comment: `p1 = p2;` has nothing to do with the class's copy assignment operator. Those are pointers.

Comment: Presumably you meant `*p1 = *p2`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: If he wants copy then he does, because the `const` member means no default assignment semantics can exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I meant *p1 = *p2. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you have written is sufficient.**

When no move constructor exists then the copy constructor will be used instead, and there's really no purpose in move semantics here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if `p1` and `p2` are pointers then you can just assign them.

In case move constructor is not present then copy constructor will be used instead.

It remains for me hard to understand what is the logical meaning of allowing assignment on something that has constant non-static parts.

Comment: Presumably the `const` member is some sort of unique ID for the instance. It's quite right that this should remain unaffected by an assignment operator, for a type with value semantics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: value semantics means, for me, that identity doesn't play a role and a unique id doesn't make much sense in such a context.

Comment: Well, I'll grant you that I guess.

Comment: In this context, the const member is a clock frequency obtained from the OS. I didn't write that part though

Comment: @randomThought: then why it's not simply a static member instead of being a const instance member?

Comment: @6502 Not sure since its in some legacy codebase. static seems to be the way to go but I didn't write that part of the code.

Comment: @6502 Its const since the class is fully defined in a header file with no cpp so declaring and initializing static const with value from a static method seems to be non-trivial.
Basically, static const int member2 = StaticMethod() doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove const from that member if you **really** need assignment